# Unable to install R package - Warning in system(cmd) : 'make' not found

Tags: r

## Error installing package 'nlme':

- installing *source* package 'nlme' ...
  ** package 'nlme' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
  ** using staged installation
  ** libs
  Warning in system(paste(cmd, "shlib-clean")) : 'make' not found
  Warning in system(cmd) : 'make' not found
  ERROR: compilation failed for package 'nlme'
- removing 'C:/Users/pp20325/Desktop/POC/KITE/KITE-R~1/BIOINF~1/renv/staging/1/nlme'
  Error: install of package 'nlme' failed

Comment: you should nt need to install `nlme`, it comes with R just use `library(nlme)`

Comment: nlme comes with R.  You don't need to install it. If you want to upgrade to a later version upgrade R itself.

Comment: yes that worked like a charm - deepseefan